# apt-get clean doesn't remove .lz4 files in /var/lib/apt/lists

Tags: 16.04, apt, docker

I'd like to remove `.lz4` files which were generated by Apt, however `apt-get clean` doesn't do the job. It removes files in `partial` dir, but not in `/var/lib/apt/lists`.

```
# apt-get -s clean
Del /var/cache/apt/archives/* /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*
Del /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
Del  
# apt-get clean
# find /var/lib/apt/lists -type f -size +10M -ls
  3685776  15304 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root     15667682 Apr 21  2016 /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_binary-i386_Packages.lz4
  3685775  15340 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root     15707199 Apr 21  2016 /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4
```

How I can clean these files using Apt command?

I'd like to remove them, so my Docker container after provisioning is slimmer.

---

Repro steps using Docker:

```
$ docker run ubuntu:xenial -it bash
# apt-get update
# apt-get -s clean
Del /var/cache/apt/archives/* /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*
Del /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
# apt-get clean
# find /var/lib/apt/lists -type f -size +1M -ls
  1182038  15340 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root     15707199 Apr 21  2016 /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_binary-amd64_Packages.lz4
  1182032  15596 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root     15968301 Apr 21  2016 /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_source_Sources.lz4
...
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## How to remove those files

It's not a good idea to remove these files unless you're really hurting for temporary disk space or you're not going to update the system's software ever again.

If you're sure that there are no APT activities taking place, including the automatic security updates you may have set up while installing Ubuntu or the automatic you-have-updates warning window, you can remove them as follows:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists
```

The next time you run `sudo apt-get update`, that directory's structure will be automatically recreated for you.

## Why doesn't `sudo apt-get clean` remove those files?

`sudo apt-get clean` won't remove any files at all in `/var/lib/apt/lists`, except for those in `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial`. This can be seen as you pointed out with `sudo apt-get -s clean`:

```
$ sudo apt-get -s clean
Del /var/cache/apt/archives/* /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*
Del /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
Del /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin
```

Note that `/var/lib/apt/lists/*` isn't listed for deletion.

This is done because the files it deletes don't prevent any APT commands from successfully running. It just has the possibility of slowing them down when things have to be redownloaded.

Deleting `/var/lib/apt/lists/*` actually causes errors with `sudo apt-get install` and `apt-cache` until you run `sudo apt-get update` again. It also makes `sudo apt-get update` take much longer, since it can't skip downloading files that haven't changed.

Answer (score 2):

You have the `universe`-repository enabled, that's why you have these files in `/var/lib/apt/lists`. The `universe`-repository provides community maintained free and open-source software. I don't think you want to disable this repository.

If you disable this repository with

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r -u universe
```

obsolete files in `/var/lib/apt/lists` will automatically get removed.

Comment: How I can disable it then? It's enabled by default in _Ubuntu Xenial_.